# How to catch application crash in DLL

Tags: dll, crash

I am coding DLL and want to send some IOCTL to Kernel eventually to attached hardware to clean-up in case of client application crashes.

The crash can be client application programmer's mistake e.g. invalid access, divide by 0 etc. In this situation, my attached hardware has to take some clean up action.

How DLL gets notified of attached client application's crash?

Comment: I do not think you can deal with crash in the dll, because the whole process is ended. The common way to do that, is to get the exit code of the process, you can write a service to get the exit code of the process, and do the clean job depends on exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can deal with all the crash in the dll, because the whole process is ended. The common way to do that, is to get the exit code of the process, you can write a service to get the exit code of the process, and do the clean job depends on exit code.

But you can still deal with some exceptions in your dll. You can use API
"AddVectoredExceptionHandler". Please read [Effective Exception Handling in Visual C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus) and [Exception Handling - Inform your users!](http://win32easy.blogspot.jp/2011/03/exception-handling-inform-your-users.html) .

Comment: References are exceptionally helpful in understanding the problem. Thanks.